# Get object key based on value inside that object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to get the key that is associated with a certain value. If I use this:

```
function findKpiAttrName (obj, value) {
  _.each(obj, function (v, k) {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty('name') && v.name === value) { return k }
  });
}

var attrKey = findKpiAttrName(obj, 'KPI Name');
```

If I `console.log(attrKey)` it returns `undefined` but I know it is finding something because if I `console.log(k)` inside the above method it prints it just fine. Is there something wrong with scope that I am missing? I am using ES5 by the way.

Any help with be great! Thanks!

Comment: `each` does not return nothing.

Comment: @davidbuzatto okay so even if I remove the `return` it still does the same thing

Comment: can Object have only one `name` property?

Comment: @Dementic yes it will only ever have one

Comment: Can you please add your input object? It'll be easier if we can see which object format you're dealing with.

Comment: Just use `_.findKey`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function findKpiAttrName (obj, value) {
  let d = null;
  _.each(obj, function (v, k) {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty('name') && v.name === value) { d = k; return false; }
  });
  return d;
}
```

Or maybe this is even better:

```
function findKpiAttrName(obj, value) {
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if ( v.hasOwnProperty('name') && v.name === value) {
      return k;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't understand why the return statement doesn't work. However, I can suggest the way that I'd do this question:

```
function findKpiAttrName (obj, value) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.find(function (key) {
    if (obj[key] === value) return true;
  })
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: `return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this? No lodash neaded for this =)

```js
function findKpiAttrName(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function(key) {
        return object[key] === value;
    }).pop();
};

console.log(findKpiAttrName({
    name: 'KPI Name',
    value: 42
}, 'KPI Name'));
```

I do like @Dementic concise solution above, but `.find()` won't work in IE9 if that is still a concern... this solution should (I think =D, maybe...it's IE after all)

Answer (score 0):

You could also one line this via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and `no lodash`:

```js
let obj = { name: 'KPI Name', value: 42 }

let fn = (o, i) => (Object.entries(o).find(([k,v]) => v === i) || [])[0]

console.log(fn(obj, 'KPI Name'))  // name
console.log(fn(obj, 42))          // value
console.log(fn(obj, null))        // undefined
```

With `lodash` and `ES5` compatibility just use [_.findKey](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#findKey) like this:

```js
let obj = { name: 'KPI Name', value: 42 }

let getKeyByValue = (obj, value) => _.findKey(obj, x => x === value)

console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, 'KPI Name'))  // name
console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, 42))          // value
console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, null))        // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```